# Angular 2+ focus on previous element with ngIf

Tags: angular, focus

Angular2+

I have a form that open on a click. When it open the `button` does not display.
I want to focus on the button when the form closed.

The code is something like this:

```
<button (click)="x=!x" *ngIf="x">Open</button>
<form *ngIf="!x">
      <input>
      <button (click)="x=!x">Close</button>
</form>
```

Such forms exist in several places, so I can't use `viewChild` in every component.

I've tried to do it with a simple directive, but it's not working because of the `ngIf`.
Here is the directive: *[live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kbl5y6)*

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appAutoFocus]'
})
export class AutoFocusDirective implements OnDestroy {
  prevButton: HTMLElement;

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document) { 
    this.prevButton = document.activeElement as HTMLElement;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.focus(this.prevButton);
  }

  focus(element: HTMLElement) {
    if (element){
      setTimeout(() => {
        element.focus();
      }, 200);
    }
  }

}
```

Everything just look great, but it's not work. Here is a [live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kbl5y6)

Any idea please?

Comment: The problem comes from the fact that you keep a reference to the button before it is destroyed. When x become false, the button is removed from the DOM. When the form closes and x becomes true, the button is injected into the DOM again, but the reference is lost.

Comment: @Sébastien do you have an idea how to do it in different way?

Comment: Not a clean way, but you could use a query selector method in your focus method. That would ensure that you get an element that is actually in the DOM.